# Pass AngularJS variable to script tag in html view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the issue.  I have a 3rd party script which needs to be embedded on my AngularJS app, in the html as a `<script>` tag.  I need to pass scope variables to this script (name, email etc). My first attempt here is to figure out if I can pass a scope variable from the controller to a script tag on page load. Perhaps there's a better approach, like making the script a template, but I'm not sure. I'm worried that if I succeed in this basic concept, that the script tag will render the real data before the variable is passed.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Angular variable: {{foo}}
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(foo); // $scope.foo?
  </script>
```

Here's the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = 'bar';
})
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5rcnqUxHRHMthHmkwVuZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed third party script(jQuery plugin or something else) to your AngularJS application you should write wrapper to this script(simple [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component))

The way you presented will not work - I guarantee

I found a simple [example](https://gist.github.com/anazimok/5415705) for you how to create AngularJS directive and wrap some simple jquery plugin:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS wrapp jquery plugin</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/master/numeric/jquery.numeric.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.directive('numberMask', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    $(element).numeric();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div>
            <input type="text" min="0" max="99" number-mask="" ng-model="message"> 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The third party script sets some variables and pulls additional JS code from an http call. Will this be a problem with the component or directive route?

Comment: I think it will not be a problem - you have to try, at the top you have a small hint. Good luck